# What is the use of "~" mark in the Perl regular expression?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I'm using boost library for regular expression in C++. What is the use of `~` mark in the Perl regular expression?

What does it denote?
e.g.

```
~myName
```

or

```
ab~dc
```

Comment: You mention "!" in the text of your question. Did you actually mean ~?

Comment: [here](http://rubular.com) you will see, that it is just a symbol

Comment: yes Jon, I mean "~" symbol, what is the meaning of it

Comment: What makes you think it has a special meaning? Did you try to experiment with regexes containing "~"?

Comment: Thanks @loldop, but I'm using Perl regular expression not the Ruby expressions

Comment: Are you thinking of the `=~` and `!~` Perl operators? These are used to invoke a regex on a variable, but are not part of the regex.

Answer (score 5):

It’s a normal character that is matched verbatim and has no special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, ~ plays no special role in perl regular expressions, so ~myName is really "~myName".